# updating JavaScript classes using template literals

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I have a limited understanding of JavaScript classes and am finding it difficult to find good resources about them to help me with my project.

I have created the following classes for a turn based game;

```js
class Player {
    constructor(name, image, location, isTurn) {
      this.name = name;
      this.image = image;
      this.location = location;
      this.isTurn = isTurn;
      this.cssClass = "player";
      this.weapon = "unarmed";
      this.health = 100;
  
      //deal with default weapon here
    }
    // get css class
    getCSSClass() {
        return this.cssClass;
      }
      getPosition() {
          return this.location;
        }
  
      // set position
      setPosition(identifier) {
         this.location = identifier;
         return this.location.toString();
      }
    }
    
  
  let player1 = new Player("player2", "css/player1.png", "", true);
  let player2 = new Player("player2", "css/player2.png", "", false);
```

I have also made a function to spawn the player on a random place on the board.  Each tile has a unique numbered id (between 1 and 150).  The random number function works fine.

below is my spawn function that i am having trouble with;

```js
function spawnPlayer(n, identifier) {
    let playerSpawn = document.getElementById(identifier);
    playerSpawn = playerSpawn.id;
    console.log(playerSpawn)


    if (occupied.includes(playerSpawn) == true) {

    spawnPlayer(n, identifier);

    } else {
       
   `player${n}`.setPosition(playerSpawn);
    console.log(("player" + `${n}`).getPosition());
    playerArray.shift();
    playerArray.unshift(playerSpawn.id);
    playerSpawn.classList.add("player");
    playerSpawn.classList.add("player" + n.toString());
    //console.log("player" + n);
    //console.log(player2.image);
    playerSpawn.style.setProperty(
        "background-image",
        "url(css/player" + n + ".png)"
    );
    playerSpawn.style.setProperty("background-size", "cover");
    }
}
spawnPlayer(1, randomise());
```

i am having trouble understanding how to use template literals in a way that i can re-use this function for both player 1 and 2 as arguments.

> ```
> `player${n}`.setPosition(playerSpawn);
> ```

this is the bit that's causing me problems.  My current error is

> Uncaught TypeError: n.setPosition is not a function
> at spawnPlayer

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also if anyone can recommend some material that explores JavaScript class implementation that would be very helpful

Thank You

Comment: `\`player${n}\`` is a string and has no identity to the `player1` or `player2` instances

Comment: Apart from Lionel's answer, you can use `global` object: `let player1 = global.player1 = new Player(...); console.log(global["player1"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `player1` and `player2` as properties of some object. Then you can access them dynamically:

```js
const obj = {
  player1: new Player(...),
  player2: new Player(...),
}

// ...

obj[`player${n}`].setPosition(playerSpawn)
```

Comment: Or you can use an array and access the players by their index